# It [has been/is?] better to keep money in a bank than to keep it under your bed in a suitcase

Tags: tense, present-tense

> It has been better to keep money in a bank than to keep it under your  bed in a suitcase.

This sentence is from an error spotting exercise as per the answer key it is error free but isn't the *has been* here wrong ? Since the sentence is saying kind of fact  isn't it better to use *is* here ?

Comment: Yes that is correct

Comment: The idea is not necessarily a universal truth. For example, if your country were to go through a massive banking/liquidity crisis, it would be better to load up those suitcases under your bed than to keep the money  in your bank.

Answer (score 2):

The present perfect conveys different information from the simple present.  Example:

> I am an American
>
> I have been an American.

The first is a statement of my current condition.  The second is a statement of my current condition *until now*.  Without any additional information, it strongly implies that the condition is *no longer true*.

In the same way, if you say that it *is* better to put your money in the bank, then you believe it to be generally true.  If, instead, you say it *has been* better, then you imply that it is *no longer* a good idea.  Both are equally valid statements, just with different meaning.